# Still not getting the email from fabric for twitter

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, twitter, twitter-fabric

I submitted my application for twitter review. They whitelisted, today morning i got a mail. I provided the privacy URL and Terms and Condition URL. Checked the request email from users box(Permissions tab). But still I am not getting the mail id. Please help..

```
    2015-11-05 10:14:32.260 Que Pics[1914:28034] Email (null), Error: Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=37 "Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.}
2015-11-05 10:14:47.699 Que Pics[1914:28034] Email (null), Error: Error Domain=TWTRErrorDomain Code=2 "The user chose not to share their email address at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The user chose not to share their email address at this time.}
2015-11-05 10:15:16.713 Que Pics[1914:28034] signed in as AbbieVys
2015-11-05 10:15:18.350 Que Pics[1914:28034] Email (null), Error: Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=37 "Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.}
2015-11-05 10:15:19.695
```

Why is this? Why so naive operation from fabric???

```
 - (IBAction)twitterButtonAction:(id)sender {

    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^
     (TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
         if (session) {
             NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
             [self userEmailIDTwitter];
             [[QPCommonClass initializeUserDefaults]setObject:[session userName] forKey:@"USER_ID"];
             [self pushToCategoryViewController];
         } else {
             NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }
     }];


}



   -(void)userEmailIDTwitter
{
    if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] session]) {
        TWTRShareEmailViewController* shareEmailViewController = [[TWTRShareEmailViewController alloc] initWithCompletion:^(NSString* email, NSError* error) {
            NSLog(@"Email %@, Error: %@", email, error);

        }];
        [self presentViewController:shareEmailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        // TODO: Handle user not signed in (e.g. attempt to log in or show an alert)
    }
```

Comment: This isn't about programming?

Comment: no!!!! Lemme post the code

Comment: @DaniellaD'Cruz This is really something for you to resolve with Twitter. I don't believe anyone can help you here as the error is entirely dependent on Twitter.

Comment: @DaniellaD'Cruz Also, if your app is whitelisted for email access you should see a separate permission that needs to be selected under Application Management Permissions at apps.twitter.com.

Comment: did you go to https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform

Comment: Yess bro!!... Cold response from them. I think twitter must enhance its support more.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I'm happy to look into this more with you @DaniellaD'Cruz, but I need more details. Can you email me at support(at)fabric(dot)io? 

Also, one thing to note is that even though you can request the user's email address, user's can reject this permission. Such as the case in this log:


"The user chose not to share their email address at this time."

Comment: @MikeB yess mike i have sent the mail yesterday itself and i have got a mail from Mr Bear Douglas. Hope for getting this issue sorted out

Comment: @PatelJigar Have you created your app in apps.twitter.com?

Comment: yes @DaniellaD'Cruz i had created app and i had also done with whitelist the app

Comment: @PatelJigar [[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"Your App Fabric Consumer key" consumerSecret:@"Your App fabric secret key"];

Comment: @PatelJigar Add this line in appdelegate inside didfinshlaunchingwithoptions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101256/discussion-between-daniella-dcruz-and-patel-jigar).

Comment: ohk then what should i do now? @Daniella D'Cruz

Answer (score 2):

The Fabric team helped us resolve the issue. Our app's info.plist had the incorrect consumer key. When you set up Fabric for the first time, it will put a consumer key in your info.plist. When you set up TwitterKit, you need to replace that key with your Twitter app's consumer key. That solved the problem for us. Thanks

Comment: Hope this may help me in future projects